# Does full rank matrix A in $F_2$ still determine a unique solution in the linear system $Ax=b$?

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

Matrix $A$ is a $n\times n$ binary matrix.

Vector $b$ is a $n\times 1$ binary vector.

The unknown $x$ is a $n\times 1$ binary vector.

When will the system $Ax=b$ have a unique solution?

Here the normal multiplication is BIT-AND and the addition is BIT-XOR. Matrix $A$ is full rank iff none of the rows can be represented as a linear combination of other rows.

Further question: How do we prove that $A$ is full rank? (Besides Gaussian Elimination, $det(A)\neq 0$ etc)

Comment: There isn't much in introductory linear algebra that cares about which field you're working over. Most of it translates between fields entirely unchanged.

Comment: @Arthur, would changing the addition from BIT-XOR to BIT-OR be any different as well?

Comment: Is $F_2$ still a field if you do that? If yes, then very little changes. If no, then you have to be more careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The answer to the question of your title is: yes.
- An answer to your final additional question is for instance: check that $\det(A)\ne0.$

The proof for these two answers is the same for $\Bbb F_2$ (or any field) as for $\Bbb R.$

Comment: Thanks! I tried the $det(A)\neq 0$ approach before. I am excluding this as well. I am looking for approaches that cannot apply to the general matrices.

Comment: What I can think of is plugging in different $x$ values and then checking the distribution of $b$. Since this is a 1-to-1 mapping the distribution should be even. Is there some way that I can verify this fact fast enough?

Comment: I think you should ask your final question in a separate post, and explicit the requirement you only added here as a comment.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4583300/how-do-we-prove-that-a-matrix-a-in-f-2-is-full-rank  Alright I have it here.:)